# Return lvalue from function in Python?

Tags: python, function, reference, lvalue

I tried to write a function which can return a reference of an element for assginment, the sample code looks like this (Python3) :

```
row_a = ["rowname","items1","items2"]
def rowname(row):
    return row[0]
rowname(row_a) = "another_rowname"
```

However, it will not work because the intepreter complains like:

`SyntaxError: can't assign to function call`

Does anyone have idea about how to implement a function like this?

Comment: @wim Sorry, I fix it..

Comment: @DeepankarBajpeyi Sure, I ran the code in both `python` and `python3`. Both complains like :   File "lvalue.py", line 4
    rowname(row_a) = "another_rowname"
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
`

Comment: Is the question really about returning lvalues or do you want a function that assigns a value to a given index in a list?

Comment: What you're trying to do is just impossible, because strings are immutable in python.  Also, the list indices are 0-based so your rowname would be in `row_a[0]` not `row_a[1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a Pythonic way of doing this. You cannot return an lvalue in Python – Python isn't C++! If you just want use a function to to set the value of the first element of a list, **just do that:**

```
row_a = ["rowname","items1","items2"]
def set_rowname(row, value):
    row[1] = value
set_rowname(row_a, "another_rowname")
```

Answer (score 0):

Return value from a function can't be used as a variable. You can rather assign the return value to a variable. Your list definition sees like you wanted to create a dictionary. Why not sat exactly what you expected to get?

Answer (score 0):

Just found a ugly way .. Thougn `setattr` needed..

```
row_a = ["rowname","items"]
def rowname(row):
    class inner:
        def __init__(self):
            self.__dict__["to_l"] = None
        def __setattr__(self,name,value):
            row[0] = value
    return inner()
rowname(row_a).to_l = 20
print(row_a)
```

Comment: No you haven't. You aren't returning an lvalue. You return an object and set the value of one of its properties.

Comment: You could also just have written `row_a [0] = 20` instead of all this code.